# Trying to Debug very glitchy blackjack game in java

Tags: java, algorithm, blackjack

First, thanks for reading this, I'm going to start by posting all code relevant to the program which you can skim or completely skip over for now.

Try to ignore all my sarcastic comments throughout the code btw they aren't directed at stack overflow :P

BlackJack file:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.InputMismatchException; 
public class BlackJack { //i should probably put a betting thing somewhere.....
  //also should probably add a thing that tells them one of the dealers cards
  //should also put something that stops 2 players from having the same name

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //honestly have no idea if i can put this here but it seems to work. keyword; seems
//good lucking counting cards with all this shuffling lol

  public void absolutelyNothing() { //maybe put a betting method here instead of a method that does nothing???
    //Do NOT Delete This Method!
  }

  public static void displayHands(Hand[] hands, String[] playerNames, int players) {

    for (int i = 1; i < players; i++) {
      display(hands, playerNames, i);
    }
    displayDealer(hands);
  }

  public static void display(Hand[] hands, String[] playerNames, int i) {
    System.out.println(playerNames[i] + " has " + hands[i]);
  }

  public static void displayDealer(Hand[] hands) {
    System.out.println("Dealer has " + hands[0].dealerDisplay());
  }

  public static boolean win(Hand[] hands, int i) {

    int value = worth(hands[i]);
    int dealer = worth(hands[0]);
      if (value == -1) {
        return false;
      }
      if (value > dealer) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
  }

  public static void winners(Hand[] hands, String[] playerNames) {

    for (int i = 1; i < hands.length; i++) {
      if (win(hands, i) == true) {
        System.out.println(playerNames[i] + " beat the dealer");
      }
      else {
        System.out.println(playerNames[i] + " lost to the dealer");
      }
    }
  }

  public static int worth(Hand hand) {

    int sum = 0;
    int aces = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < hand.howManyCards(); i++) {
      Card card = hand.getCard(i);
      int value;
      if (card.getNumber() == -10) {
        aces++;
        value = 11;
    }
    else {
      value = card.getNumber();
    }
      sum+= value;
  }
  for (int i = 0; aces > i; i++) {

    if (sum >= 22) {
      sum = sum - 10;
    }
  }



    if (sum >= 22) {
      return -1;
    }
    return sum;
  }

  public static void dealerTurn(Deck deck, Hand[] hands) {

    int worth = worth(hands[0]);

    while (worth < 16) {
      dealCard(deck, hands, 0);
    }

  }

  public static void playTurn(Deck deck, Hand[] hands, int i, String[] playerNames) {

  //  System.out.println(playerNames[i] + " hit?" + " Your hand is worth " + worth(hands[i]) );
    boolean hit;

    displayHands(hands, playerNames, hands.length);

    while (true) {

      if (worth(hands[i]) == -1) {
        System.out.println("Bust");
        break;
      }

      System.out.println(playerNames[i] + " hit?" + " Your hand is worth " + worth(hands[i]) );
      try {
     hit = input.nextBoolean();
    }

    catch (InputMismatchException exception) {
      System.out.println("Please enter \"true\" or \"false\"");
      continue; //pretty sure this continue is causing the glitch where if you don't enter a boolean it goes insane
    }

      if (hit == true) {
        dealCard(deck, hands, i);
      }

      else {
        break;
      }

    }
  }

  public static void everyoneGo(Deck deck, Hand[] hands, int players, String[] playerNames) {

    for (int j = 1; j < players + 1; j++) { //players go
      playTurn(deck, hands, j, playerNames);
    }
      dealerTurn(deck, hands);
  }

  public static Deck newHand(Deck deck) {

    Deck newDeck = new Deck();
    return newDeck;
  }

  public static void dealCard(Deck deck, Hand[] hands, int i) {

    deck.shuffleDeck();
    //goodluck counting cards
    hands[i].addCard(deck.getCard(0));
    deck.removeCard(0);
  }

  public static void giveNextCard(Hand[] hands, Deck deck, int i) {
    hands[i].addCard(deck.getCard(0));
    deck.removeCard(0);
  }

  public static Hand[] firstTwoCards(int players, String[] playerNames, Deck deck) { //gives dealer cards first an I'm too lazy to fix

    deck.shuffleDeck();
    //seriously good luck
    Hand[] hands = new Hand[players + 1]; //dealer is hands[0]

      for (int i = 0; i < players + 1; i++) {
        hands[i] = new Hand(playerNames[i]);
      }

      for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < players + 1; i++) {
          giveNextCard(hands, deck, i);
        }
      }

    return hands;
  }

  public static String[] getNames(int players) {

    System.out.println("What are the names of the players?");
    String[] playerNames = new String[players + 1];
    playerNames[0] = "Dealer";
    for (int i = 1; i < players + 1; i++) {
      playerNames[i] = input.next(); //something with this line the last time you use it
    }
    return playerNames;
  }

  public static int peoplePlaying() {

    System.out.println("How many people are playing?");

    int players = input.nextInt();

    return players;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int players = peoplePlaying();

    String[] playerNames = getNames(players);

    Deck deck = new Deck();

    Hand[] hands = firstTwoCards(players, playerNames, deck);

    everyoneGo(deck, hands, players, playerNames);

    winners(hands, playerNames);
  }
}

//if you're smart you would have realized all this shuffling has absolutely no effect on counting cards lol now figure out why
```

Hand File:

```
public class Hand extends CardList {

  public Hand(String label) {
    super(label);
  }

  public void display() {
    System.out.println(getLabel() + ": ");
    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(getCard(i));
    }
    System.out.println();
  }

}
```

Deck File:

```
public class Deck extends CardList {

  public Deck(String label) {
    super(label);

    for (int suit = 0; suit <= 3; suit++) {
      for (int rank = 1; rank <= 13; rank++) {
        addCard(new Card(rank, suit));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Cardlist File:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class CardList {

  public String name;
  public ArrayList<Card> cards;

  public CardList(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
  }

  public String toString() {
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++) {
      s = s + cards.get(i) + ", ";
    }
    return s;
  }

  public String dealerDisplay() {
    return cards.get(0).toString();
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public Card getCard(int i) {
    return cards.get(i);
  }

  public int howManyCards() {
    return cards.size();
  }

  public void addCard(Card card) {
    cards.add(card);
  }

  public void removeCard(int i) {
    cards.remove(i);
  }

  public void swapCards(int i, int j) {
    Card wait = cards.get(i);
    cards.set(i, cards.get(j));
    cards.set(j, wait);
  }

  public void shuffleDeck() {

    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) { //not sure how well the algorithm works but if you do it 10 times it shouldn't matter how bad it is
      for (int i = 0; i < howManyCards(); i++) {
        int j = (int) (Math.random() * howManyCards());
        swapCards(i, j);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

and finally the card object:

```
public class Card {

  int number;
  int suit;

  public static final String[] NUMBERS = {null, null, "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};
  public static final String[] SUITS = {"Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades", "Hearts"};

  public Card(int number, int suit) {
    this.number = number;
    this.suit = suit;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return NUMBERS[number] + " of " + SUITS[suit];
  }

  public int getNumber() {

    if (number == 14) { //used to tell if its an ace in blackjack file
      return -10;
    }
    if (number < 11) {
      return number;
    }
    else {
      return 10;
    }
  }
}
```

Alright so hopefully you didn't kill yourself by attempting to read all of that and I realize my code style/organization could use some work.

Anyways their are a few things that are very weird with the program that I can't seem to figure out. Sometimes the program will run fine and you can play a full game with lots of players but other times it throws a bunch of exceptions.

basically if you bust (go over 21) the program throws this 100% of the time:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at CardList.getCard(CardList.java:31)
    at BlackJack.dealCard(BlackJack.java:151)
    at BlackJack.dealerTurn(BlackJack.java:93)
    at BlackJack.everyoneGo(BlackJack.java:138)
    at BlackJack.main(BlackJack.java:209)
```

btw if someone could explain what it means by exceptions at lines that don't exist such as 653 (the first message) that would be very helpful.

It also throws the same exception some of the time even if you don't bust which I'm assuming is the dealer busting as the dealer plays automatically obeying the regular casino rules for dealers.

If anyone can figure it out it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You're trying to deal a card from an empty deck. Time to do some debugging and then some fixing. Use a debugger to get things moving faster, and look carefully at the lines given to you by your exception stacktrace.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've deleted the comment to avoid confusion, but I didn't say the bug was in Java, I just said that the line 653 that is referred to by the exception stacktrace is in ArrayList.java, in response to the question "what it means by exceptions at lines that don't exist such as 653".

Comment: @samgak: I am sorry, I misread what you were stating.

Comment: To the OP, look at the lines of **your** code that are referenced in the stacktrace including `CardList.java:31`, `BlackJack.java:151`, etc...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for your help, I looked at the code, mainly where it tries to remove a card from the deck (line 31/151)  and its method. The thing I don't get is how could the array list possibly be empty seeing as every method removing a card is giving to someone and as I'm only playing the game using 1 or 2 "players" their are less than 52 cards in play which is how many the array list has in the first place. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok I'm still not sure what was wrong but I "fixed" the problem by making the 52 card deck into a 520 card deck with 10 of each card like casinos I still get the error with busting and indexoutofboundsexpcetion

Comment: Again, use a debugger to see the state of your variables as you run your program. Eclipse and NetBeans both have nice debuggers bundled with them, and these will allow you to see what is happening.